# How do I scramble the bits in a struct?

Tags: c++, random, bit, memset, packing

I have a pair of `pack/unpack` functions that operates on a structure of data.

In order to effectively unit test them,
I would like to put this structure into a random state, and then verify that the packing and unpacking returns the original structure.  It might look something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < LOTS_OF_TESTS; ++i){
    Struct s;
    randomize_bits(s);
    CHECK ( s == UnPack(Pack(s)) );
}
```

**Is there a function that takes a generic type, and randomizes all of the bits?**

Conditions:
 - There are no pointers in the structure
 - There could be fundamental types
 - There could be nested structs
 - There could be arrays
 - I'm not concerned about padding

---

I thought I might be able to use something with [memset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset),
buy my attempt is giving me a runtime exception.

```
template<typename T>
void randomize_bits(T & t){
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(t); ++i){
        std::memset((&t)+i,random_uchar(),1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not a simple cast: `(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>t)[i] = random_uchar();`?

Comment: Are you sure the runtime exception is related to that piece of code? I guess the bug is elsewhere...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes, I think so.  http://ideone.com/jLVvv4

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: it'll generate a SIGSEGV or similar - not a C++ exception - because `(&t)+i` operates in units of `sizeof T`.  Your cast idea above's much better, though the first left-parentheses should be moved before `t`.

Comment: This will not work for floating types because NaN is not equal to itself. Inutialize your struct field by field with random values of appropriate type

Comment: @n.m. doesn't that depend on the `Struct::operator==`, rather than beign a problem for the `Unpack`/`Pack` or "randomisation"?

Comment: @Tony do you mean that `s == s` would also fail? Yes it would.

Comment: @n.m. ...or equally, `s == s` can work too if you care to provide a suitable `operator==` overload.  Anyway, if the idea's to have some tests that don't have to worry about where `s == s` "works" or write `==` overloads, it might be better to do the penultimate comparison with `memcmp`.

Comment: @Tony yes, if you make an operator that always returns true it will also pass the test. Don't think it is desired though. If you want to conpare with memcmp (why is this penultimate?) there's no need to deal with structs and types and all their complications. Just pack and umpack character arrays.

Comment: @n.m. *"always returns true"* - sure, but an `operator==` that's generally meaningful while special casing nans to compare equal is reasonable for testing (and sometimes general use), and doesn't undermine the test.  "penultimate" because each Struct value goes through generation, packing and unpacking and then is finally tested.

Comment: @n.m. regarding the comparison with character arrays - very probably true, though for all we know `Pack` and `Unpack` might do something that wouldn't work with character arrays, perhaps based on an assumed base class, or tests for specific data members that get special handling (e.g. "if there's a `bool isValid` member pack it into one bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Basile, this solves my problem, and iterates over the memory correctly.

```
template<typename T>
void randomize_bits(T & t){
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(t); ++i){
        reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&t)[i] = random_uchar();
    }
}
```